# JS: Get Latitude from External Website (not Google Maps)

Tags: javascript, location, preventdefault

I am trying to get the latitude for an address from an external website, not from Google Maps. I have succeeded in entering the address (New York in my test), using Javascript. I also submitted the form via Javascript. However, the value for latitude does not appear when I use Javascript. It does appear if I click Submit with the mouse.

One of the thoughts I had was that the page was reloading on submit, so I tried to stop this default behaviour. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to see or access the latitude anywhere.

Here is my JS code:

```
window.open("http://www.external_website.com", "_self");

function get_latitude() {

    var place = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var place_id = place.getAttribute("id");
    document.getElementById(place_id).value = "New York";

    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    var form_id = form.getAttribute("id");
    document.getElementById(form_id).addEventListener("submit", 
    function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        })

    document.getElementById(form_id).submit();
    window.lat= document.getElementById("lat").value;
    };

    get_latitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the ajax call to the webpage.

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"webpage.html",
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data) {
           var out = "";
            $(data).find("your selectors").each(function(loop, item){
                out += $(item).html();
            });
            data = out;
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function() {
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
});
```